# Tags история-языка, linguistics & slavic

Tags: discussion, tags

Since the questions with these tags have been downvoted by a vast majority of community members, I suggest removing these tags as useless.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with that. I'll explain why:

- [language-history](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-history) or **история-языка**, is useful because I'm sure users will ask about some historical question. This doesn't mean *highly specialized Linguistics* questions, but for example, a question like "How did we get to use the expression X?". That's a fine question, I guess.
- [linguistics](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics): We don't even have this tag. We have [sociolinguistics](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sociolinguistics) and you're the only one who [used it](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1797/71) and... it worked. :)
- [slavic](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slavic): This is useful because unavoidably people will ask in questions about Slavic. The problem is when these questions get too specialized or technical. But if you're asking about Russian compared to other languages for some reason, it might be useful.